# Excel formula ( combination of IF and Sum )

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a formula for Column C as shown below.
I am trying to identify
(1) if any of the ITEM contains the word RED ( or the value in cell B1), THEN
(2) capture the value in column C and sum it up.
(3) If the value sums up less than 10,000 (or the value in cell B2), then it will return the word "OK". Otherwise, return the word "STOP".

Side Note : There will be continuous input in  Column A and each time when I key in new item that contains the word red AND quantity value adds up the figures above whether greater or lesser than 10,000, it will show me either "OK" or "STOP".

[image]

Comment: What is your expected result?  For 2nd requirement, should it be column B (exactly is B5:BXXX?);  And have you check the `SUMIF` (https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-if-cells-contain-specific-text)

Comment: If it is a running total type situation, =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("RED", A2)), B2+C1, C1) throw a condition around it to test for the 10,000 value either in that column or another.

Could also do a =SUMIFS($B$1:$B2, $A$1:$A2, "RED") then again wrap it in a conditional to display your OK/STOP

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(AND(SUMIFS($B$5:$B5,$A$5:$A5,"*RED*")>$B$2,NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("*RED*",$A5,1,0)))),"STOP","OK")
```

For practical reasons I would switch things and put a list of colors in there, first identify the corresponding color then the corresponding limit number then match the running total with said limit.
Confer [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-773Ttgo1z6bWcyU25ubW9ack0/view?usp=sharing) to find a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put in C5:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1,A5)),IF(B5<=$B$2,"OK","STOP"),"")
```

And in C6:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("STOP",$C5:C5,0)),"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1,A6)),IF((SUMIF($C$5:C5,"OK",$B$5:B5)+B6)<=$B$2,"OK","STOP"),""))
```

Then simply copy down from C6 as you need it. But Keep in mind that a key word like `"as"` will also be found if the word `"base"` is in the ITEM.

Comment: Hi Dirk, One word: GENIUS. Thanks a lot!